# AWS X-Ray trace has reached its maximum allocated quota

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-xray

I have a long workflow so the trace size has exceeded 100KB(Max allowed), so I am getting just half of the data in the service map. What happens when trace size exceeds the limit? How can I check the rest of the traces?
I have step functions that run MAP jobs resulting in a lot of trace sub-segments and increasing the size of the trace. Can I exclude those segments from the path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to reduce the number of subsegments generated by your StepFunction workflow. If your workflow produces too much trace data for the trace size limit, it is not possible at this time to visualize it.